# How to respond with a pretty-printed JSON object using play framework?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, pretty-print

How can one send, using the Play! framework, a JSON response that is formatted to be human-readable?

For example, I'm looking for something like:

```
def handleGET(path:String) = Action{ implicit request =>
  val json = doSomethingThatReturnsAJson(path,request)
  request.getQueryString("pretty") match {
    case Some(_) => //some magic that will beautify the response
    case None => Ok(json)
  }
}
```

My search led me to [JSON pretty-print](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/6GWHDkZOXYw), which was not very helpful on it's own, but it did say the ability should be integrated in future versions. That was play 2.1.X, so, I guess it already exists somewhere in the 2.2X version of play?

Comment: Is there any benefit to having beautified JSON?  If it's just for debugging, you can use a browser plugin like JSONView for Firefox to format it.  Sending beautified JSON just wastes bandwidth.

Comment: default behavior is the minified JSON. only when supplying the `pretty` flag as a query param, you'll get the result beautified. benefits? it's readable. and sometimes you'll want to see a human readable representation of your'e data. take a look at [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.com) for example. they do just that. by supplying a pretty flag, you can see all sort of data on your node/cluster. this is quite usefull.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Play framework has pretty printing support built-in:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json
Json.prettyPrint(aJsValue)
```

So in your case, it would be sufficient to do the following:

```
def handleGET(path:String) = Action { implicit request =>
  val json = doSomethingThatReturnsAJson(path, request)
  request.getQueryString("pretty") match {
    case Some(_) => Ok(Json.prettyPrint(json)).as(ContentTypes.JSON)
    case None => Ok(json)
  }
}
```

Comment: would play take care of everything a json response should have even if i use a `String` instead of `JsObject`?

Comment: Probably not, but "everything" really is just the content type. I edited my answer to show what is necessary to enforce other content types, it's no biggie.

Answer (score -3):

You can use Gson to pretty print Json string, don't know about scala; but here is a Java example which you can convert to scala and use it:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(obj);
System.out.println(jsonStr);
```

Comment: this won't help me. since i'm returning an http response, i need to use play's json object, and the play framework would take care of all sort of annoying things i don't want to define my self. like `content-type` header, etc'... and BTW, i can get the pretty json as string directly. no need for external tools. but again, the string won't do me much good :\